# Why mkdir doesn't work with GString?

Tags: c, linux, glib

If I use just `"/home/user/.some/qwe"` instead of `homedir->str`, it works.

```
struct stat st = {0};

GString* homedir = g_string_new(NULL);
g_string_append(homedir, getenv("HOME"));
g_string_append(homedir, ".some/qwe");

printf("%s", homedir->str);

if (stat(homedir->str, &st) == -1) {
    int res= mkdir(homedir->str, 0777);
    g_string_free(homedir, TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be able to avoid this bug and always build valid path names by using [`g_build_filename()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-build-filename):

```
char *homedir = g_build_filename(getenv("HOME"), ".some", "qwe", NULL);
printf("%s, homedir);
if (stat(homedir, &st) == -1) {
    int res = mkdir(homedir, 0777);
}
g_free(homedir);
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, `$HOME` does not end with `/`. So, for your case, `HOME` = `/home/user`, and string for mkdir would look like: `/home/user.some/qwe` (notice missing `/`).
Try changing your code to add that missing slash, for example use:

```
g_string_append(homedir, "/.some/qwe");
```

With that said, all you really needed is to know how to debug - just printing value of your string to stdout would make it immediately obvious.